# Doctrine self join entity

Tags: doctrine-orm

I'm having trouble self joining an entity on oneToMany. My entity looks like:

```
/*
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="IntegritBundle\Entity\UserMessage", inversedBy="related", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="parent_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 * @Serial\Expose
 * @Serial\Groups({"all", "basic"})
 */
public $parent;

/**
 * @var ArrayCollection
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="IntegritBundle\Entity\UserMessage", mappedBy="parent", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 * @Serial\Expose
 * @Serial\Groups({"all", "basic"})
 */
public $related;
```

But when querying it I get the error `Notice: Undefined index: parent`
`

It’s the `mappedBy` in the `$related` property that’s causing the problem but I don’t see why

Comment: Be careful with cascade. In your code every time UserMessage is removed, all of its child AND parent are removed. I think it's not what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was a missing * on the docblock for $parent :)